# Find the marginal density of $Y$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)=\frac{5}{8}$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

The random vector $(X,Y)$ has joint density function given by

$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(x+3y)e^{-(x+y)}$ if $x,y\geqslant0$ and $f(x,y)=0$ otherwise.

Find the marginal density of $Y$ and $\mathbb{P}(Y>X)=\frac{5}{8}$.

Attempt:

$$\begin{align*}
        f_{Y}(y)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)dx\\
        &=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}(x+3y)e^{-(x+y)}dx\\
        &=\frac{1}{4}(1+3y)e^{-y}.
    \end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
        \mathbb{P}(Y>X)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}(x+3y)e^{-(x+y)}dydx\\
        &=\frac{5}{8}.
    \end{align*}$$

Comment: Your attempt is correct.